# java.lang.NullPointerException on converter app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, converters

I'm currently creating a live currency converter app with API calls, but whenever I click the Button to convert the currency, my app crashes and I get this line:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.gson.JsonObject com.google.gson.JsonObject.getAsJsonObject(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.converterproject.MoneyActivity$1$1.onResponse(MoneyActivity.java:70)
```

Here's some of the code I wrote:

```
MoneyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = RetrofitBuilder.getRetrofitInstance().create(RetrofitInterface.class);
            Call<JsonObject> call = retrofitInterface.getExchangeCurrency(MoneyTo.getSelectedItem().toString());
            call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
                    JsonObject res = response.body();
                    JsonObject rates = res.getAsJsonObject("rates");
                    double currency = Double.valueOf(MoneyEd.getText().toString());
                    double multiplier = Double.valueOf(rates.get(MoneyFrom.getSelectedItem().toString()).toString());
                    double result = currency * multiplier;
                    MoneyTextView.setText(String.valueOf(result));


                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

So apparently `JsonObject rates = res.getAsJsonObject("rates");` is the line that's causing the problem. I really don't know how to fix this so I would be very grateful for some help

Comment: `NullPointerException`

Comment: Seems like your `rates` object is receiving null value that's why `NullPointerException` is happening. You can debug the project and check that you are getting the correct value to your object

Comment: Can you provide a url for the api call in the question so someone else could replicate the same issue? Without that there's not much we can say other than that `res` is null... Maybe the string it returns is a JSONArray not an object, or not Json at all?

Comment: I found the problem, my url for the api call didn't work anymore. I found a new one and now it's perfectly working. Thanks for helping me guys!:))

Comment: This error is saying that some data is missing. first add toast or log in `onResponse` and `onFailure` and check whether retrofit is getting response or not

Answer (score 0):

it's appear your response is JsonObject and you don't need to get res which is JsonObject => `JsonObject res = response.body();` as JsonObject.

so if you remove this line

```java
 JsonObject rates = res.getAsJsonObject("rates");
```

and use res instead. I think this will work.